# Windows Store entirely missing from Windows after reset

Tags: windows-10, windows-store, uwp

I've been having some issues with the Windows Store on my laptop. Today, after finding the need to reinstall WSL, I finally resolved to dig into the problem.

The app folder was beyond salvaging what with the permissions nightmare that WindowsApps is, so I reset and kept my user files. I started my fresh copy of Windows to find that the Windows Store is **completely missing** -- i.e., absolutely no files for the Store app itself to be found anywhere.

I tried transferring the Store files from my desktop to my laptop and re-registering the manifest to no avail. The app crashes immediately. Event Viewer shows a number of errors:

```
Error   1/24/2020 9:44:49 PM    DistributedCOM  10010   None
The server Microsoft.WindowsStore_12001.1001.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe!App did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

Error   1/24/2020 9:44:09 PM    AppModel-Runtime    69  None
Failed with 0x490 modifying AppModel Runtime status for package Microsoft.WindowsStore_12001.1001.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe for user COLE-XPS\Cole (current status = 0x0, desired status = 0x20).

Error   1/24/2020 9:39:17 PM    ESENT   455 Logging/Recovery
svchost (8772,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Error -1023 (0xfffffc01) occurred while opening logfile C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log.
```

I am thoroughly convinced by now that Microsoft support is beyond worthless and will not be able to help with this issue considering how (seemingly) rare it is. Any ideas?

Comment: If you create a new user does the Windows Store work?

Comment: Did you check your HDD/SSD for errors using a SMART error reader? I suggest using crystaldiskinfo or Speedfan.

Comment: @Ramhound No, there's nothing to source the Store app from. The problem here is that the files are outright gone, and not just that the manifest isn't registered; creating a new user doesn't fix this, and it's the same thing as using `Add-AppxPackage`.

Comment: @NatsuKage I don't think that's the issue. I ran CrystalDiskInfo just in case and found no errors. There would most likely be other things acting up if this was the case.

Comment: Good. Did you reset the store using Settings>Apps>Microsoft Store>Advanced Options> Reset ?

Comment: Try running  Windows Store Apps troubleshooter

Comment: You seem to have played with the permissions of reserved Windows folders, ending up with a mess that Microsoft Support rightfully does not need to fix up for you. Try a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), but mind your backups.

Comment: @cbryant02 - So you are not even going to try my suggestion of creating a new profile?

Answer (score 0):

The Folders mentioned are missing.

Here you can create ...Local\TileDataLayer & Database.

Have you tried

Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }

It is supposed to get/add any package missing.

Also, make sure your "Services" are turned on for all required services, most importantly

**Client License Service (ClipSVC)**

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to restore rights to "c:\Program Files\WindowsApps" folder and subfolders.
It is a good ideea to re-register apps using Add-AppxPackages before.

1. Take correct onwership form Program Files -> in order to access this hidden folder ( i was unable to see it in cmd until this step was made )
2. Unhide WindowsApps folder ( from cmd -> attrib -H -S  or using explorer )
3. Take ownership of this folder AND subfolders (from TrustedInstaller owner )
4. Allow ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES, System and of course your user/Administrators to acces WindowsApps folder and subfolders. #### WARNING #### Please check the rights in order not to open doors for security issues !!! ##### WARNING END ###### I trust Microsoft, then Everyone,System,Administrators to have full access to this folder works for me, but for others can be a security issue.
5. Check if any "corupted" acces is there; Check if any other strange rights are there;If yes, delete or repair them as appropriate. For me, deleting them worked.

6.Restore ownership on Program Files and WindowsApps folders.

Please note that, in order to restore original rights, you will need to take ownership and then restore-it using another trick (adding  "NT Service\TrustedInstaller" as ownership at the end )

Please note that additional steps may be required to be made before or after this fix:
-check ClipSvc service startup type
-reset WindowsStore cache via wsreset

Above instruction will fix:
-Windows Store fail to start; windows store reset via wsreset errors regarding cache permission
-Calculator fail to start
-Snip&Sketch , ScreenSnip (from Notification Area) and other affected Windows Store Apps
-Some "failed to register to DCOM" errors

Note: Windows Reset, Refresh, InPlace Update WILL NOT FIX THE ISSUE - only clean install will reset rights on affected folder.

Note: Do not **debloat** your windows without looking what the script will do.Be sure that you really understand what you will run !!!

For refs, other ideeas:
https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/116591-store-apps-close-immediately-event-10010-distributedcom-3.html
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-restore-trustedinstaller-owner-system-files-windows-10